# Creating Git repository without double folders

Tags: git, eclipse

When I create a Git repository using Eclipse Team option it moves the main project folder inside the repository creating folder structure like `workspace_name/repo_name/project_name` with any contents only being inside the latter. I want to have it be `workspace_name/repo_name` since the names of repositories and projects are almost always the same.

Is it possible to do that in Eclipse without workarounds? Or maybe having git repo and Eclipse project with the same root folder is a bad idea?

Clarification, as requested by comments:
What I'm doing is `right-click a project` => `Team` => `Share Project...` => `Create...` (new git repository). When you go into that repository's folder, there's the Eclipse project's folder inside. I want my project files directly inside the git repository. The question asks if that can be done by changing some setting in Eclipse or using a different in-Eclipse way of creating git repositories out of current projects.

Yes, I am using an empty workspace, separate from the current one.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Please tell which steps you have taken exactly to make it clear why you are asking this question at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your last question to yourself comes close.  Git repositories should never be within the Eclipse workspace.  For instance, put all of your git repositories in ~/git, and create your workspace(s) as "~/workspace-...".  Create projects in your workspace by importing from the git repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how I solved it:

1. In Eclipse create java project in the location that you want
2. Right click on Project->Team->Share project
3. Check the "Use or create repository in parent folder of project" checkbox
4. On "Share project" window click on the location to highlight it
5. On the same window click on the "Create repository" and "Finish" button

The project files will be on the same level as the ".git" folder.
[Check the checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvkNY.png)